# Exception when using Geolocation with Dart

Tags: geolocation, dart

Working in Dart with Geolocation. The geoposition object passed to the callback does not always have altitude, speed or direction. My question is how I check for this to prevent an exception from being thrown?

I know I can use exception handling but would prefer to detect the situation. At least in the Dart Editor the debugger pauses execution, it seems, even if the exception is caught...

I've tried

```
if(solution.coords.altitude==null) { ... }
if(solution.coords.altitude is num) { ... }
```

These cause exceptions. In the debugger altitude does not show as an available field in the object. On a device, with the right settings, altitude is included.

How do I deal with this?  Surely there is some way to test that the optional fields are there or not.

Just to reiterate, the fields are not showing up, they do not show as null, they are not there.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you can paste in the actual exception, that would be great, thanks! Also, this might be a bug.

Comment: Here's a tested sample showing Dart + Geolocation. Can you compare your code? https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-html5-samples/tree/master/web/geolocation/trip_meter

Comment: This is the exception information...
UnsupportedOperationException: [info: ..\..\..\..\..\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\bindings\dart\custom\DartCoordinatesCustom.cpp:40]

Comment: In the geolocation callback, the code triggering this exception is

'
    try {
      alt=solution.coords.altitude;
      vacc=solution.coords.altitudeAccuracy;
      altitueSet=true;
    }
    on UnsupportedOperationException {
      alt=0.0;
      vacc=0.0;
      altitueSet=false;
    }
'
Specifically the first statement in the try block.

Answer (score 1):

What does `coords` return? I find it hard to believe that the `altitude` is not even available, because it's a getter. Maybe the whole `coords` (i.e. the `Coordinates` object) is `null`?

Try:

```
if (solution.coords is! Coordinates) {
    print('No coords!');
}
```

The exception is thrown because it's unimplemented: http://src.chromium.org/multivm/trunk/webkit/Source/WebCore/bindings/dart/custom/DartCoordinatesCustom.cpp

If you run as JavaScript, things work well, because it does not use the Dart VM.

Comment: coords contains latitude, longitude, and accuracy one each call back. It may also contain altitude, altitude accuracy, heading and/or speed. But these last few are not always part of the returned object. I can see this in the Dart debugger and if I check, even null check, on altitude, I will get an exception.

Comment: On devices, like my IPad, I do get an altitude and accuracy estimate. Its too bad that the desktop would have no altitude number to supply but worse that I cant find a gracefull way to deal with this for both running my code on a desktop and a mobile device.

Comment: Yes I know altitude is not implemented on some systems, on the three I try, altitude is not implemented on the PC but is when ran on the iPad or Google Nexus 7.  My specific problem is how, programatically would I go about detecting if it is implemented? I'm hoping there is a straightforward way to detect this kind of condition before an exception is generated. It seems like a serious issue to me.

Comment: Even more interesting things.  It seems that altitude is not implemented for coords in Dartium but they are in Chrome on the PC. The values are null, and that is easy to deal with. Maybe the problem is local to Dartium.

Comment: OK, I've confirmed. Seems that only Dartium is missing Altitude and the other geolocation parameters, in Dartium trying to access these will create an exception. For Chrome on the PC, iPad, and Nexus 7, these are implemented and may be null.  To deal with it on Dartium is a pain, but I can get by, just have to have two versions of the position handler and switch for production till its fixed in the code base for Dartium.

Comment: Yes it's Dartium. For now you could maybe compile to JS, because that works.